# SSIS - Ultra large file (500MB) fails with OutOfMemory exception

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

I have a SSIS pacakge which loads data from a non-standard XML file to database table with a xml datatype column . I call it a non-standard file as it has some invalid characters like tabs in it which I remove using a script task and it has hierarchy tags in it which can be present for some keys and not for others. I had tried using XSLT, but it did not work as all the attributes (tags) appear as separate output in SSIS XML source rather than separate output. So I read the whole XML file as a single column and single row as a flat file. The package runs fine when loading small files (upto 8 Mb) but fails when the size is large.  When trying to load a 500 MB file, the script task failed due to OutOfMemory error. So the file was sent in smaller chunks. Now, the script task worked for processing a 90 MB file but fails in the DFT as SSIS only reads part of the XML and not the whole file because of which the DFT fails at the destination. I adjusted MaxbufferRows to 1 and DefaultBufferSize to 100 MB from the defaults of 10000 rows and 10 MB respectively. I found that the flat file source is reading 8193 KB data (8388609 characters).

Please advice.

Note : I am running the SSIS package from Citrix. I am storing the whole xml document in a table and then using .nodes to extract the relevant information to be stored in relevant stage tables.

Comment: That is, in truth, one huge xml file (probably about 500M characters). Are you not able to separate the file into smaller chunks?

Comment: Also, where are you running the package, in SSDT or is the SSIS Service running it? If the latter, is the package running in 32bit mode?

Comment: i am running the package in SSDT from Citrix. The original file which failed was of size over 500 MB. This file failed in the cleansing step (Script task removing invalid characters for an XML) .Then I requested the file to be sent in smaller chunks. A file of size 88 MB was sent which went through the above mentioned script task but then failed in the subsequent data flow task where I read the all the file contents as a single value (Single XML document) and load in a table with column having data type XML.

Comment: The issue is that the source reads only a part of the xml and tries to load that in the destination table resulting in an error. I checked this by replacing the destination table with a flat file as I could not use a data viewer because of the DT_TEXT column from the source flat file.

Comment: SSDT is part of Visual studio, which is only a 32bit application, so I'm not surprised it's running out memory (as it'll need to load the entire file into memory, along with all of it's transformations, etc). Why not deploy and run the package? SSDT is for development. Your SQL Server *(should* have more memory processing power than your Citrix Session, and runs as a 64 bit application.

Answer (score 1):

In your Script task, open a [StreamReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netframework-4.7.2) to process the file incrementally, and stream it into a nvarchar(max) or XML column in SQL Server.  No need to load the whole thing in SSIS.

See [SqlClient Streaming Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sqlclient-streaming-support)

Edit your question to include a pared-down file, including the transformations you need to make if you need an example.

Comment: That might not (probably won't actually) work with an XML file because of the need to match opening/closing tags.

Comment: @user1443098 I don't understand why not.

Comment: @David, I did not understand how you would stream the data incrementally in the nvarchar column. If SSIS reads the data in chunks (depending on the buffer size), there would be multiple rows which would need updates after the first insert. XML data type is nout of question as an incomplete record would result in a invalid XML.

Comment: @Shaggy1755  I'm proposing loading _exclusively_ with ADO.NET streaming in the script task.  Bypassing the SSIS pipeline entirely.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft  OK, suppose you are streaming an XML file.  At the very least you need to parse the root tags, which of course cover the entire file!  So your very first call needs to read the whole thing.  Streaming doesn't help

Comment: For streaming XML reading use an XmlReader.  It gives you forward-only streaming access to the XML nodes.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2  If you just need to strip/escape invalid characters (which I think is OPs scenario), then you can just use a StreamReader.

Comment: Sure, but that's an abstraction.  The XmlReader has the same issue.  That's just pushing down a level

Comment: @David, Thanks!!! I get it. I will try using asynchronous script component to read the complete xml and then write it. I had actually thought of it as the last option. I am really curious to know why even after specifying the Buffer size to be 100 MB and the maxBufferRows to be 1, SSIS is reading and writing just a part of the xml (8193 KB data with 8388609 characters).

Comment: I think you don't want a Script Component.  A Script Task in the Control Flow.

Comment: Hi Guys, Sorry for the late reply.